# SQL 2005 Trigger Question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, triggers

Can I ascertain the name of the stored procedure that caused the trigger to fire from within the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure offhand, but what if it wasn't triggered by a stored procedure?

You might be able to use [`DBCC INPUTBUFFER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187730.aspx) as in [this article](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/tracking_sql_statements_by_triggers.htm).